# Pandas complex processing with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

My data is grouped by id.  In each group, it is sorted by colB.  The logic I need to implement is as follows:

If colA is blank, and colD is either (2,3, or 4), 
then create a column called 'flag' and set flag = 1 in the last non-zero row of colC. Set the flag to 0 in all the other rows of that group, where colC is non-zero. 
Remove the rows where (colA is blank, and colC is 0) for that particular grouping.

Repeat above procedure for all other 'id' groups.

(For rows where colA is non-blank, I can set the flag to what I need.)

Here is the data I have:

```
id  colA    ColB    colC      colD
1           10      1352.23   2
1           11      706.87    2
1           12      1116.6    2
1           13      0         2
1           14      0         2
1           15      0         2
2           2      6884.03    3
2           3      2235.97    3
2           4      3618.04    3
2           5      11745.42   3
3   2013    1      345.98     0
```

and here is what I would like to get after processing it.

```
id  colA  ColB  colC      colD  flag
1         10    1352.23     2   0
1         11    706.87      2   0
1         12    1116.6      2   1
2          2    6884.03     3   0
2          3    2235.97     3   0
2          4    3618.04     3   0
2          5    11745.42    3   1
3   2013   1    345.98      0   0
```

The data contains many thousands of such groupings.  I am hoping someone can help me in figuring out what the Python code to do the above processing would look like.  I have a basic familiarity with the groupby function, but not to the extent to be able to figure out how to do the above.

---

Here is the code I am trying to use.  The code give errors: 
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'."

I am trying to set the "flag" to NaN when I detect the zeros in colC that I eventually want to remove, so I can drop them easily, in a later step.

```
def setFlag(grouped):
    for name, group in grouped:
        for i in range(group.id.size):
            drop_candidate = (
                     pd.isnull(group.iloc[i]['colA'])&
                  ( (group.iloc[i]['colD'] == 2) |
                    (group.iloc[i]['colD'] == 3) |
                    (group.iloc[i]['colD'] == 4)    ) 
                )

            last_nonZero = group[group != 0].index[-1]

            if (  (drop_candidate & (group.iloc[i]['colC'] == 0))  ):
                group['flag'] = np.nan
            elif ((drop_candidate & (group.iloc[i]['colC'] != 0)) & (last_nonZero != i)):
                group['flag'] = 0
            elif last_nonZero == i:
                group['flag'] = 1

        return grouped

df.groupby('id').apply(setFlag)
```

Here is the code to re-create the test dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([
    ('id', [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]), 
    ('colA', [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2013]),
    ('colB', [10,11,12,13,14,15,2,3,4,5,1]),
    ('colC', [1352.23,706.87,1116.6,0,0,0,6884.03,2235.97,3618.04,11745.42,345.98]),
    ('colD', [2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,0]),
    ('flag', [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,]),
    ])
```

Comment: Hi Alexander:  I've posted my latest attempt.

Comment: can you add a command for creating the sample data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are three parts to your process:

1) Get rid of rows where colA is null and colC == 0. Work on reducing your dataframe first

if it is AND logic:

`reduced_df = df.loc[(df.colA.notnull()) & (df.colC != 0), :].copy()`

if it is OR logic:

```
reduced_df = df.loc[(df.colA.notnull()) | (df.colC != 0), :].copy()

    id  colA  colB      colC  colD  flag
0    1   NaN    10   1352.23     2   NaN
1    1   NaN    11    706.87     2   NaN
2    1   NaN    12   1116.60     2   NaN
6    2   NaN     2   6884.03     3   NaN
7    2   NaN     3   2235.97     3   NaN
8    2   NaN     4   3618.04     3   NaN
9    2   NaN     5  11745.42     3   NaN
10   3  2013     1    345.98     0   NaN
```

2) Now you are ready to work on part two which is flagging the last column of a group. Since the default flag value is 0, start with that

`reduced_df.loc[:, 'flag'] = 0`

3) You can find duplicate values using `duplicated` and then make sure colA is null

```
reduced_df.loc[~reduced_df.colD.duplicated(keep='last') & reduced_df.colA.isnull(), 'flag'] = 1

reduced_df

    id  colA  colB      colC  colD  flag
0    1   NaN    10   1352.23     2     0
1    1   NaN    11    706.87     2     0
2    1   NaN    12   1116.60     2     1
6    2   NaN     2   6884.03     3     0
7    2   NaN     3   2235.97     3     0
8    2   NaN     4   3618.04     3     0
9    2   NaN     5  11745.42     3     1
10   3  2013     1    345.98     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks dmb.  This certainly works!  I was not aware of the duplicated() method.  Your idea also got me off the track I was on with row by row processing on 'groupby' output.

Comment: Seems I can't accept an answer since I don't have enough points (I don't see any options to do so).  To conclude, can either of you point out what was wrong with trying to process row by row in each group, the return from groupby()?.  Clearly row by row processing is not the best way of doing what I needed, and both of your answers helped me to 'frame' my problem in a better way than I originally planned.  But, what is the correct way of processing output from groupby on a row by row basis, in a general way, so the output from that processing can be used to update the original dataframe?

Comment: Groupby under almost all circumstances requires an operation that produces an aggregate output (so you can take a mean of the group, but you cannot just get the output again) - try something like df.groupby('some column').agg({'another column': lambda x: x}). You will get an error

Comment: oh, and to accept an answer there should be a check mark underneath the scores by our answers

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with using the `apply` method.  I think it does what you are asking for:

```
df['flag'] = df['colD'].shift(-1) #use as a placeholder to compare consecutive 'colD' vals
df['flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['flag']!=x['colD']) & 
                  (np.isnan(x['colA'])) & (x['colD']>0) else 0, axis=1)
```

Please let me know if that works!  (You'll need to have numpy as np imported btw). Also, if you want to limit this to only cases of 2,3 & 4, you'll have to change the last part from `(x['colD']>0)` to be `(x['colD']>1) & (x['colD'] < 5)`

Comment: Thanks Greg.  I like the technique of the shift to check for last element.  
I could make your suggestion work by adding some logic to remove the rows where colC = 0 and colA is empty, first.  Appreciate the help.  It shows a cleaner way as opposed to what I was thinking with row by row processing with 'groupby'

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.loc[~(pd.isna(dd.colA)&dd.colC.eq(0))]
    if dd1['colA'].isna().all()&dd1['colD'].isin([2,3,4]).all():
        idx1=dd1.query("colC !=0").tail(1).index.tolist()
        return dd1.assign(flag=np.where(dd1.index.isin(idx1),1,0))
    return dd1.assign(flag=0)

df1.groupby('id').apply(function1)
```

out：

```
    id  colA  colB      colC  colD  flag
0    1   NaN    10   1352.23     2     0
1    1   NaN    11    706.87     2     0
2    1   NaN    12   1116.60     2     1
6    2   NaN     2   6884.03     3     0
7    2   NaN     3   2235.97     3     0
8    2   NaN     4   3618.04     3     0
9    2   NaN     5  11745.42     3     1
10   3  2013     1    345.98     0     0
```